# Xamarin.Forms Azure App Service SQLite integration - WP 8.1 Issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I'm trying and setting up an Azure App Service database (easy table) integration on my Xamarin Forms App, following the instructions I found on these two posts: [this one](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/), by James Montemagno, and [the one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/sync/azure-mobile-apps/) I found on a Xamarin Developer Guide.

Now, everything works fine on the Android App but I've got an issue on Windows Phone 8.1: I can build my app, but it crashes when executing the `var something = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);` instruction (*{"Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}*).

Here's my SQLite & Azure-related reference:

[image: here].

Any idea on why this issue is happening?

Thanks!

Jacopo

---

**UPDATE - 25/11/2016**

I tried building the same project with the same libraries in Windows UWP, and it works.

Is there a WP 8.1 non-compability with the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore I couldn't find any reference about, maybe?

Could this issue be related to the Visual C++ 2015 Runtime Package (UWP) vs the Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package one (WP8.1)?

Comment: Have you followed with the article you provide to Install the SQLite for the Universal Windows Platform? And add SQLite for Universal Windows Platform and Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps extensions to your project?

Comment: Since you are using Windows Phone 8.1, please ensure you Install SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1.  You could find this information at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data)

Comment: Hi Jambor! Thanks for your answer. Now, as you can see from the image I already installed and referenced SQLite for WP8.1. I tried following your latest suggestion, but I can't add the SQLite for UWP and Visual C++ 2015 Runtime reference in my WP8.1 project. Any other suggestion?

Comment: If you [Install SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=716920). Does it work?

Comment: Yeah, I already installed it (I tried a lot of combination, as a matter of fact, in order to get WP 8.1 working) but it doesn't work. If it can be of any help, I'm using Visual Studio 2015, while these packages should be for VS2013. Could this be an issue, in your opinion?

Comment: Hi @Jambor-MSFT! I've updated my question, since I found out everything works in the UWP project. I think there might be a WP8.1 compatibility problem, maybe because of the Visual C++ Runtime Package (and SQLite) referenced. Any thoughts about it? Could that be it?